# random floating point error with subquery order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am running sql server 2008 database, i am using the following query in a web app, but for the point of debugging the error i am directly running the query in management studio.

I am getting the following error - An invalid floating point operation occurred. when running this query.

```
select p.Id as Id,  p.CatId as CatId, p.MetaName as MetaName ,p.Active as Active,p.HasChildren as HasChildren ,p.Mlevel as Mlevel ,p.ParentId as ParentId ,p.Type as Type, p.VOrder as VOrder, p.UrlOrder as UrlOrder, Count('*') as VCount 
from MetaDataValues as m 
left join MetaData as p on m.MetaDataId = p.Id
left join Adverts as a on m.AdvertId = a.Id
where a.Status = 1
and a.ExpDate > current_timestamp and 
m.AdvertId in 
(select m2.AdvertId from MetaDataValues as m2 left join MetaData as p2 on m2.MetaDataId = p2.Id where p2.MetaName = 'meta1' 
and m.AdvertId in (select m3.AdvertId from MetaDataValues as m3 left join MetaData as p3 on m3.MetaDataId = p3.Id where p3.MetaName = 'meta2' 
and m.AdvertId in (select m4.AdvertId from MetaDataValues as m4 left join MetaData as p4 on m4.MetaDataId = p4.Id where p4.MetaName = 'meta3' 
and m.AdvertId in (select ad9.Id from Adverts as ad9 where dbo.GetDist(ad9.X,ad9.Y,ad9.Z,52.9131514,-2.9313405) < 969))))
group by p.Id, p.CatId, p.MetaName,p.Active,p.HasChildren,p.Mlevel,p.ParentId,p.Type, p.VOrder, p.UrlOrder
```

To explain its the GetDist function that is causing the problem, if i move this up in the subqueries to the top  level the query runs fine?? This isnt an ideal as the code that builds this query is coded in a certain way and i dont want to alter it. so here is the query that works, exactly the same but a different order!

```
select p.Id as Id,  p.CatId as CatId, p.MetaName as MetaName ,p.Active as Active,p.HasChildren as HasChildren ,p.Mlevel as Mlevel ,p.ParentId as ParentId ,p.Type as Type, p.VOrder as VOrder, p.UrlOrder as UrlOrder, Count('*') as VCount 
from MetaDataValues as m 
left join MetaData as p on m.MetaDataId = p.Id
left join Adverts as a on m.AdvertId = a.Id
where a.Status = 1
and a.ExpDate > current_timestamp and 
m.AdvertId in 
(select m2.AdvertId from MetaDataValues as m2 left join MetaData as p2 on m2.MetaDataId = p2.Id where p2.MetaName = 'meta1' 
and m.AdvertId in (select ad9.Id from Adverts as ad9 where dbo.GetDist(ad9.X,ad9.Y,ad9.Z,52.9131514,-2.9313405) < 969)
and m.AdvertId in (select m3.AdvertId from MetaDataValues as m3 left join MetaData as p3 on m3.MetaDataId = p3.Id where p3.MetaName = 'meta2' 
and m.AdvertId in (select m4.AdvertId from MetaDataValues as m4 left join MetaData as p4 on m4.MetaDataId = p4.Id where p4.MetaName = 'meta3' )))
group by p.Id, p.CatId, p.MetaName,p.Active,p.HasChildren,p.Mlevel,p.ParentId,p.Type, p.VOrder, p.UrlOrder



GetDist code

USE [MVC]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[GetDist]    Script Date: 02/20/2013 17:05:00 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDist] 
    (
    @xaxis float,
    @yaxis float,
    @zaxis float,
    @CenterLat float, 
    @CenterLon float
    )
RETURNS float
AS
    BEGIN

declare @CntXAxis float
declare @CntYAxis float
declare @CntZAxis float
declare @EarthRadius float 

set @EarthRadius = 3961
set @CntXAxis = cos(radians(@CenterLat)) * cos(radians(@CenterLon))
set @CntYAxis = cos(radians(@CenterLat)) * sin(radians(@CenterLon))
set @CntZAxis = sin(radians(@CenterLat))

return (@EarthRadius * acos( @XAxis*@CntXAxis + @YAxis*@CntYAxis + @ZAxis*@CntZAxis))


    END
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the GetDist function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like GetDist may be calculating the distance between a pair of latitude/longitude values.  I have a lot of experience with this.  Most GetDist functions like this use the Arc Cosine function "ACos".  The parameter for this function is limited to the range -1 to 1.  If you try to pass a value outside this range, you will get a domain error in SQL Server.  If your GetDist function uses a CLR function, the error would be within your .net code and would have a slightly different message.

When dealing with floats, you have to be aware of weird rounding issues.  For example, if your calculations would return a value of 1.00000000000001, and you pass that in to the ACos function, you will get an error.

There's a lot of speculation here, and I could be completely off base, but please consider this and spend a couple minutes doing some research.

Based on your GetDist function posted above, I would suggest a relatively minor change:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDist] 
    (
    @xaxis float,
    @yaxis float,
    @zaxis float,
    @CenterLat float, 
    @CenterLon float
    )
RETURNS float
AS
    BEGIN

declare @CntXAxis float
declare @CntYAxis float
declare @CntZAxis float
declare @EarthRadius float 
declare @Temp float

set @EarthRadius = 3961
set @CntXAxis = cos(radians(@CenterLat)) * cos(radians(@CenterLon))
set @CntYAxis = cos(radians(@CenterLat)) * sin(radians(@CenterLon))
set @CntZAxis = sin(radians(@CenterLat))

Set @Temp = @XAxis*@CntXAxis + @YAxis*@CntYAxis + @ZAxis*@CntZAxis
If @Temp > 1
    Set @Temp = 1
Else If @Temp < -1
    Set @Temp = -1

return (@EarthRadius * acos(@Temp))

    END
```

Even if this doesn't solve your original problem, it will at least protect you from weird float/precision problems.

Comment: Ive just posted above getdist, yep you are correct about what the function is doing and i do understand that the range is limited to -1 to 1. The odd thing is if i re-order the subqueries ie pu the distance one first, it works! So its queuing the dataset. Also if i remove one of the other subqueriers it also works.

Comment: It does not matter what order you write your query. The T-SQL query optimizer will evaluate the entire query and determine the best order in which to execute the query.  I would say that this is a simple, "you got lucky one way, and unlucky another".  The only way to correct this problem is to determine the underlying problem and fix it there.  Hopefully the change I suggested for the function will take care of the problem.

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem, i wont try and understand why, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem an invalid operation or something more like "Error converting data type varchar to numeric"?  This is a fairly common problem, when numeric data is being stored as a string.  It works when the string looks right, but then fails at other times.

Are all the arguments to `getDist()` of the correct type?  Is the return value a number?

I would guess that the filtering at the higher level filters out the bad values that are causing the problem.

Comment: Yep they are all correct and of the type float, it works when there is less where clauses thus a bigger dataset, so i dont think it can be data problem